# Need help splitting a data string in Unity

Tags: c#, database, unity-game-engine, split, string-operations

So in my game I'm trying to get some articles from a database and split the data in separate articles. Here's my code:

```
IEnumerator Start () {
    WWW articleData = new WWW ("http://mywebsite.com/getsomedatabase.php");
    yield return articleData;
    string articleDataString = articleData.text;
    DevideData (articleDataString);
}

void DevideData(string data)
{
    //Column 1 = article name
    //Column 2 = article id
    //Column 3 = option 1
    //Column 4 = option 2
    //Column 5 = option 3
    //Column 6 = change in values that appear directly after article has come in
    //Column 7 = change in values after option 1 has been chosen
    //Column 8 = change in values after option 2 has been chosen
    //Column 9 = change in values after option 3 has been chosen
    //Column 10 = change in values after no option has been chosen

    List<string> articles = new List<string> ();

    string subData = data;

    for (int i = 1; i < Regex.Matches (data, "|NEXT|").Count; i++) {
        articles.Add(subData.Substring(0,subData.IndexOf ("|NEXT|")));
        subData.Replace (subData.Substring (0, subData.IndexOf ("|NEXT|")), "");
    }
}
```

articleDataString is basically a long string of formatted data, and each article is separated by |NEXT|. However, the method I'm using to split the string, (I don't even know if it works yet.) is too heavy for the machine to handle. That's why I'm asking if there's a more efficient, lightweighted way of separating the long string.

Comment: Stop with the splitting stuff. Use json or xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, you can use the String array overload. Like this:

```
articleDataString.Split(new string[] { "|NEXT|" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That's way easier than what I was trying to do haha.

Comment: Yes, this! I would also add that by replacing the delimiter `|NEXT|` with something more compact, such as a vertical bar | (or similar), will reduce bandwidth and save a little overhead during the Split.

Comment: Hmm... Good point. I'll change that as well then. Thanks again!

Comment: @Amalox if this answers your question, don't forget to accept it. :)